# How to change/raise an old variable when opening the app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am new to Swift and already tried to search on this topic, but I don't know how it's called, so I'm asking it now. I want to make a sort of Cookie Clicker. Every time I press the button there will be more money.
I already managed to save "the money" when I open the app, but now I want to add to that "old" money when I click the button. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var employers = 0
var money = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var moneysecond: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var employees: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func clickbutton(_ sender: Any) {
        money = money + 20
        score.text = "$\(money).-"

        UserDefaults.standard.set(score.text, forKey: "dollar")
        score.text = "$\(money).-"
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "dollar") as? String {
            score.text = x
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do not store *some* `String` into the `UserDefaults` but the actual value of `money`, e.g. an `Int`. And set the value of money initially.

Right now you set the displayed text to the value you have stored, then on click you increment a `money` variable which does not have *anything* to do with the value read from the UserDefaults, therefore you lose the information of what was previously set during the last application run.

Proposal:

- move `money` into the `ViewController`
- change `viewDidLoad` to read a value of `UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dollar")` into `money`
- in `viewDidAppear` use the value of `money` to set the text
- in `clickbutton` remove the first or second `score.text` assignment and do not store `score.text` but `money` in the `UserDefaults`

Comment: Thx! It works, now the only problem there's left is that the label is only visible  when I clicked the button. How can I make the label visible before I clicked on the button (when I open the app)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the same idea as luk2302's suggestion but in code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var moneysecond: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var employees: UILabel!

    var money = 0
    var employers = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        money = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dollar")
    }


    @IBAction func clickbutton(_ sender: Any) {
        money = += 20
        score.text = "$\(money).-"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(money, forKey: "dollar")

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        score.text = "$\(money).-"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! It works, now the only problem there's left is that the label is only visible  when I clicked the button. How can I make the label visible before I clicked on the button (when I open the app)?

Comment: Thx! It works, now the only problem there's left is that the label is only visible when I clicked the button. How can I make the label visible before I clicked on the button (when I open the app)?

Comment: The code is supposed to show the saved value when the view appears.